# Why Gnome CPUFreq settings seem to have no effect?

Tags: cpufreq

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64 and trying to set constant CPU frequency for all CPUs. Here is the status:

[image]

Why some of the CPUs disregard the Min/Max frequencies set in CPUFreq app?